# Relationship between operator "is" and "TypeMirror.isSubtypeOf"

Tags: dart, dart-mirrors

Accordingly to  the `'dart:mirror'` documentation on `bool isSubtypeOf(TypeMirror other)`

```dart
  /**
   * Checks the subtype relationship, denoted by [:<::] in the language
   * specification. This is the type relationship used in [:is:] test checks.
   */
  bool isSubtypeOf(TypeMirror other);
```

If I correct understand the documentation on `"bool isSubtypeOf(TypeMirror other)"` than I think that it should work as `"operator is"`.

This code work as expected:

```dart
import "dart:mirrors";

void main() {
  var objectMirror = reflectType(Object);
  var result1 = objectMirror.isSubtypeOf(reflectType(bool));
  var result2 = Object is bool;
  print("Object is bool: $result1");
  print("Object is bool: $result2");
}
```

Output:

```
Object is bool: false
Object is bool: false
```

But I cannot understand "is this result correct or not"?

```dart
import "dart:mirrors";

void main() {
  var dynamicMirror = reflectType(dynamic);
  var result1 = dynamicMirror.isSubtypeOf(reflectType(bool));
  var result2 = dynamic is bool;
  print("dynamic is bool: $result1");
  print("dynamic is bool: $result2");
}
```

Output:

```
dynamic is bool: true
dynamic is bool: false
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `is` operator takes an object instance on the left and a type on the right, and checks whether the object is an instance of the type (or any subtype of the type).
The tests `Object is bool` and `dynamic is bool` both give false, because you are testing whether a Type object is an instance of bool. If you wrote `Object is Type`, it would be true.

The `isSubtypeOf` tests give the expected results: Object is not a subtype of bool, and dynamic is a subtype of bool. The dynamic "type" is both a subtype and a supertype of all types according to the `<:` relation.

Personally I don't see `dynamic` as a type, as much as an alternative to having a type. It's the programmer's way of saying "trust me, I know what I am doing", which is why any test involving dynamic will generally say "yes". It represents some type, or types, that the programmer omitted to write, but which would be perfectly correct if they were there.

As for the title question, the relation is:

```dart
(reflect(o).type.isSubtypeOf(reflectType(Foo))) == (o is Foo)
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a bug to me:

```dart
/**
 * Checks the subtype relationship, denoted by [:<::] in the language
 * specification. This is the type relationship used in [:is:] test checks.
 */
bool isSubtypeOf(TypeMirror other);
```

Comment: Unpleasant. Especially when working with reflection on generic type and their arguments and use of this method (isSubtypeOf) spread out throughout the code. I'm a bit tired to make corrections in my code.

Comment: Understandable. Have you filed a bug? Can you please add the link then.

Comment: I initially thought that I was wrong. And I decided to ask. Link to issue: https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=18119

Comment: You don't thinks that answer such as "Looks like a bug to me:" without any additional information are not enough for answer? Maybe just adding the comment would be enough? Especially that the error not in the documentation, but in the actual implementation. Upvote on yours answer is mine but for me would be enough the comments in my question.

Comment: No problem. My question was incorect. It contains wrong code.